# Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a secured area of my site where I can add/update/delete database entries.  I am trying to update the script from mysql to mysqli.  Everything works except for the "update" part.  When I fill in the new information and click "update", it gives me this error:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli,
>   string given in
>   /home3/tarb89/public_html/aususrpg.net/charbase/updated.php on line 19

I'm not sure what is wrong here; I'm a complete newbie, so my apologies.

Here is my update.php code:

```
<?php
    // Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$id = $_GET['id'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM characters WHERE id = '$id'");
$my_array = array($c_z);
extract($my_array);

?>

<form id="FormName" action="../charbase/updated.php" method="post" name="FormName">
<table width="448" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">

<tr>
<td width="150" align="right"><label for="name">Name: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php echo stripslashes($name) ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<input name="" type="submit" value="Update">
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
```

The other issue I have with the update.php page is when it displays the table, the inputs should display the information already listed in the database; currently, it shows the name field but the input section is empty.  It should display the name data already in the database (then I can replace it with whatever I want it to update as.)

Here is the updated.php code:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$id = $_POST['id'];

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["name"]), $con);

$rsUpdate = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE characters SET name='$name'
WHERE id='$id'");

if($rsUpdate) { echo "Successfully updated"; } else { die('Invalid query: '.mysql_error()); }
?>

<a href="index.php">Back to index</a>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  This thing is driving me bonkers.

---

**Different issue:  see above update.php code.**

When I click on a link next to a database entry, called "Update Information", it takes me to update.php?id=charactersid

Currently, it displays an empty input form.  I can input information and hit "update" and it WILL update correctly.

However, when I am taken to the update.php page, I want it to display the input form except the values should all equal what is already in the database.

For example:

What it currently shows:

Name: [empty input box]

What I want it to show:

Name: [current name listed in the database]

So the value of the input should be the information for that character; so that when I want to update, I can see what is already listed as information for that character and change/delete/add whatever else I need to.

Does that make more sense?

Comment: Connection comes first. http://us2.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using it the opposite way:

```
string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )
```

So it should be:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($_POST["name"]));
```

Source: http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string

Since you're using MySQLi I would suggest you to just jump into prepared statements rather than real_escape, like this:

```
<?php 
// Your database info 
$db_host = 'host'; 
$db_user = 'user'; 
$db_pass = 'pass'; 
$db_name = 'database';

// POST data
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = trim($_POST["name"]);

$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if ($con->connect_error)
{
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "UPDATE characters SET name = ? WHERE id = ?"; 
if (!$result = $con->prepare($sql))
{
    die('Query failed: (' . $con->errno . ') ' . $con->error);
}

if (!$result->bind_param('si', $name, $id))
{
    die('Binding parameters failed: (' . $result->errno . ') ' . $result->error);
}

if (!$result->execute())
{
    die('Execute failed: (' . $result->errno . ') ' . $result->error);
}

$result->close();
$con->close();
echo "Successfully updated";
?>
<a href="index.php">Back to index</a>
```

To select the character name:

```
<?php 
// Your database info 
$db_host = 'host'; 
$db_user = 'user'; 
$db_pass = 'pass'; 
$db_name = 'database';

// POST data
$id = $_POST['id'];

$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if ($con->connect_error)
{
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT name FROM characters WHERE id = ?";
if (!$result = $con->prepare($sql))
{
    die('Query failed: (' . $con->errno . ') ' . $con->error);
}

if (!$result->bind_param('i', $id))
{
    die('Binding parameters failed: (' . $result->errno . ') ' . $result->error);
}

if (!$result->execute())
{
    die('Execute failed: (' . $result->errno . ') ' . $result->error);
}

$result->store_result();
if ($result->num_rows == 0)
{
    die('No character found...');
}

$result->bind_result($name);
$result->fetch();
$result->close();
$con->close();
echo $name;
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much!  Any idea on how I can get <input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php echo stripslashes($name) ?>"> to display the current database data for that column?  It currently shows up empty but the updating part works like a charm now.

Comment: @Lec you have to make a select query before loading the page with that account id. If my answer solves your current issue kindly check it as the right answer.

Comment: I changed my updated.php code to the above; it works, but it also displays this error: Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home3/tarb89/public_html/aususrpg.net/charbase/updated.php on line 20 --- and I will - I have to wait a few more minutes before it will let me.

Comment: Do I need a separate select query from what's already there: $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM characters WHERE id = '$id'");

Comment: I changed my update.php code to what you have listed above; no errors, but it returns: "no character found..."  On my index page where it lists all of the database data, there's an "Update Information" link which I click, and want it to send me to the update form where it lists a form with all of the current information in it.  I'm sorry if I'm not making sense.  This is hard to explain, haha.

Comment: This is on line 20: if (!$result->bind_param('si', trim($_POST["name"]), $_POST['id']))

Comment: @Lec Fixed that error see update and no I am not understanding your previous message try posting some code so I can see what you're trying to do. You can use the edit link on your question and update it with your current in use code and any other extra code

Comment: @Lec on an additional note, the second code will give u `no character found...` when the ID does not exist.

Comment: I updated my question above to try and give a clearer explanation on what I'm trying to achieve...

Comment: Make a page called `characters.php` instead and read all characters from that id paginated and when one is clicked sent it to the `update.php` page. Also don't forget to use PHP session and a login page otherwise anyone that knows how your system works will be able to edit anyone's else character

Comment: Right; this area of the website is secured.  I have an index.php page which displays all of the current data.  Next to each character are two options: delete character | update information  When I click "update information" it sends me to the update page for that character's ID.  I want the inputs of that update form to display the current information for that character.  Basically, I think in my update.php code above, my echo striplashes($name) part isn't actually echoing the name, which is what I want it to do.

Comment: you don't need to use `striplashes` if you're using MySQLi with prepared statement like I have shown on the above last code, and if u try my code u will see it will print the character name if the id exists.

Comment: I'm not explaining myself correctly and I deeply apologize.  I hope you're not too annoyed with me right now. >.>  Let me try to simplify my question.  How can I get the <?php echo '$name' ?> part of <input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php echo '$name' ?>"> to actually echo the name of the character ID selected?

Comment: exactly as you wrote above but removing the '' from it. `<input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">`