# Update user profile page with PHP MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a social website, so far everything is good with the loggin and logout etc... but when it comes to the edit profile page I cant figure out my error can somebody suggest whats wrong or is there a better way to approach this Update Profile page.

The error I am getting is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$firstname' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\change.php on line 28

My PHP code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
}
else {
echo "You have not signed in";
}
?>
<?php
include_once ("php_includes/db_conx.php");     
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$u' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
$user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$username = $row["surname"];
$firstname = $row["firstname"];
$surname = $row["surname"];
$weight = $row["weight"];
$height = $row["height"];
}

function filter($date)
{
    return trim(htmlspecialchars($date));
}

$username = filter($_POST['username'])
$firstname = filter($_POST['firstname'])
$surname = filter($_POST['surname'])
$weight = filter($_POST['weight'])
$height = filter($_POST['height'])

if (username)
{

$sql = mysql_query ("UPDATE users SET username='$username', firstname='$firstname', surname='$surname', weight='$weight', height='$height' WHERE username='$username'")
or die (mysql_error());
}
?>


<form action="change.php" method="post"> 
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br />
    Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br />
    Surname: <input type="text" name="surname"><br />
    weight: <input type="text" name="weight"><br />
    height: <input type="text" name="height"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `username='$u'` be `username='$username'`?

Comment: the error is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$firstname' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\change.php on line 28

Comment: I changed that but still same error

Comment: Your code is so wrong and prone to people mess with it, you assign the username from the session to $username and right after you reassign it to the result of the SQL query and then again you replace it with the user input from the form which is highly unsafe and unwanted.

Comment: In regards the error, you are missing several semi-colons.

Comment: _“I have created a social website”_ … and I don’t even know enough of the syntax basics to fix an effing parse error …

Comment: @ CBroe silly mistakes sometimes are hard to see sorry and thank to everyone for your help.

Comment: Not to mention you are not checking back if the username the user is trying to change on the form is the same username on the session in fact username should not even be present on the form at all you should use the session username that was most likely stored from the login otherwise they can edit any username data that they know.

Comment: @Prix I am very new to this so I do have many mistakes you have been a great help I need to fix the username.

Comment: And last thing I would point out is, you're using MySQLi but you're not taking advantage of one of it's best feature, the prepared statements to prevent SQL injection and you are mixing together MySQL old library and MySQLi which is very bad.

Comment: @Prix Would you know how to bring the data from the profile page, as they should only be able to change their name and details not username etc... also how would i call the user from session only.

Comment: On your login page you are storing the username on the session called `$_SESSION['username']` all you need to do is reuse that instead of publicly giving then the username field. [Here is a simple MySQLi code with prepared statements that you can use as reference.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736844/warning-mysqli-real-escape-string-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-string-gi/21736892#21736892) Using prepared statements you can remove your filter function as it will do it for you and your filter function wasn't safe anyway.

Comment: @Prix thanks will look into that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $username = filter($_POST['username']);
 $firstname = filter($_POST['firstname']);
 $surname = filter($_POST['surname']);
 $weight = filter($_POST['weight']);
 $height = filter($_POST['height']);
```

You need to terminate each statement/ line with `;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = mysql_query ("UPDATE users SET  weight='$weight', height='$height' WHERE username='$username'")

i think you have to create like this 


$sql = mysql_query ('UPDATE users SET username ="'.$username.'" WHERE username="'.$username.'"');

$sql = mysql_query ('UPDATE users SET firstname="'.$firstname.'" WHERE username = "'.$username.'"');

$sql = mysql_query ('UPDATE users SET  surname="'.$surname.'" WHERE username = "'.$username.'"');

$sql = mysql_query ('UPDATE users SET  weight='".$weight."' WHERE username =  "'.$username.'"');





$sql = mysql_query ('UPDATE users SET height="'.$height.'" WHERE username="'.$username'"');
```

paste this codes.

Answer (score -1):

You need to terminate each line of code with a semicolon. Line 27 (and the next four lines) are missing the semicolon.